# RaspBMC: Only pi user has access to external HDD

Tags: raspbmc, hard-drive

I have an external (NTFS) HDD which RaspBMC automounts on `/media/Iomega HDD`.  It's owned by `pi` with 700 permissions.

I'd like a second user to be able to get access, but chmod doesn't appear to work.

How do I change the properties?

The entries in `fstab` don't appear to relate to the automounting process, so I don't know how the mounting is being done.

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults         0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620        0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p7  /boot           vfat    defaults,noatime         0       0   
/dev/mmcblk0p8  /               ext4    defaults,noatime 0       0
```

The relevant line from `mount` is

```
/dev/sda1 on /media/Iomega HDD type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: Running `mount` should show current mount points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` and getting the UID, then put the following into fstab:
`UUID=//// /media/mountdir filesystemtype rw,defaults 0 0`.

The trick is to make the mountdir and chmod it to 777 before running `sudo mount -a`

Try it, I might have made a mistake somewhere, and as always, remember to backup your fstab file before changing it.